# What's going on with Windows Installer technology and VS not supporting it?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, installshield

I just started a new job where they use both WiX and InstallShield to create installers. I was busy learning WiX and then had to jump to another project that uses InstallShield, so I googled InstallShield and got to a page on MSDN that says "It replaces Windows Installer technology, which Visual Studio no longer supports". Why does VS not support Windows Installer Technology? Does that mean that eventually I'll have to stop using WiX?

Comment: No, its still supported but is only available as an extension rather than by default, as for why? Id guess money as installshield is proprietary while wix is free.(According to wiki, last updated 3mo ago, although the MSDN page your referring to talkd about VS15, although that may be as the extension is only supported by 2013)

Comment: Update, Ive just checked and you can download the wix toolset for VS2017, so you appear to have nothing to worry about, especially as wix has a 4.0 release in the making with the preview being updated frequently

Answer (score 1):

They still and will support Windows Installer for a long time. However, because their own support for Visual Studio Installer Projects was very limited they (probably) decided to let somebody else give it a try on doing something else.

**1)** **On the long run**, Microsoft probably wants us all to move to [AppX (Desktop Bridge and UWP)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop), but this will take at least 5-10 years, in the most optimistic scenario, in my opinion. They are putting a lot of effort into this migration because it is a crucial part of their bet on universal apps. (*i.e. they need to get more apps in the store, and this is the simplest and fastest way for developers to repackage as AppX their existing code base, without rewriting it*).

AppX packages still have a lot of limitations (you **can not** do drivers, services, or any other machine resources - everything must run in user mode), so there will be a lot of work to be done. Also, some *heavy duty* apps will simply not be suitable for this migration.

**2)** **On a similar underlying technology** as AppX packages there also [App-V packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/appv-v4/overview-of-application-virtualization), widely used for a few years now for deployment of apps in enterprises. However, as I said these are designed for enterprise usage, not for the consumers, so this is not a complete replacement for Windows Installer, but in my opinion it does represent a better solution for the problems encountered by enterprises (i.e. running multiple versions of the same software side by side, compatibility issues with software written on XP, highly improved management and performance for VDI environments, etc...)

Comment: I think the parenthetical in your first point was supposed to be *"can **not** do drivers..."*

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Installer technology being referred to was Visual Studio Installer projects (.vdproj). It was gone for a few versions then it was back. (Don't know the current status.) It was not a good tool for anything but the simplest Windows Installer packages and used custom actions were none were needed. It was however at Microsoft product.

The WiX Toolset is an open source project and not a Microsoft product (though is has been used for several Microsoft products). It's aim is to support building any reasonable Windows Installer package. It should be around as along as Windows Installer is relevant.